# Consideration for paused flow

Tags: scheduled-flow

I need to develop a program in Salesforce that processes flagged records in a custom object every hour, for this I built a scheduled (once only) flow which calls has a subflow element that contains the code and a pause element which is configured to wait and resume after 1 hour. This way I will execute the subflow every hour and I expect it to run forever once the flow is activated. What could be the associated risks/considerations with this approach ?

Answer (score 1):

The only real concern is that if the flow crashes somehow, you'll lose your infinite loop. It'd be better to schedule it daily and have the flow pause 22 times (to get 23 hours of coverage), which will allow it to resume the next day if any problems occur.

Alternatively, you may consider writing Apex Code to take advantage of the Apex Scheduler. You can use 1 hour granularity to have it repeat infinitely, even if it crashes. As a bonus, you'll have logs so you can see if the code crashed.

Comment: Great suggestion - thank you very much I prefer the first option as it is code free alternative